# How to increase FPS in spritekit game with lot of SKShapeNodes?

Tags: sprite-kit, skshapenode

I need a suggestion. I am making a game with lots of SKShapeNodes. So my FPS is about 18. Has anybody suggestions about how to increase FPS in games like this? Amount of SKShapeNode in the full game scene are 220.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SKShapeNode` is rather performance intensive because SpriteKit is *rasterising* (computing the pixels of your shape) **every** frame instead of calculating it once and than reusing it.

The two options I see are :

- Creating `SKTexture`(s) object(s) with your shape nodes, and than displaying those textures with `SKSpriteNode` instead of displaying directly your `SKShapeNode` objects.
- Making some/all of your `SKShapeNode` objects children of `SKEffectNode` and set its `shouldRasterize` property to `true`, what it means is that it will rasterise the `SKEffectNode` children once, cache what has been rendered and reuse it while there is no change.

What you should use depends on what you are trying to achieve, is the shape of those nodes changing over time ? Are those shapes moving around ? Is it all of them changing/moving or only some of them ?

Comment: Thanks, Trevor Anne Denise! I am using these shapes just for moving and if it needs deleting, than spawning new shapes time after time. So is that first option better for me?

Comment: @NurassylNuridin You are welcome, just one thing to keep in mind : caching is really efficient only when there is no change to the shapes, so cache what's not changing. If you just want to move some nodes, move directly the node that caches them, so it will just be "moving a texture", not redrawing everything.

Comment: But by the way, I believe moving SKEffectNode might in some cases trigger a "new render" of it's children.

Comment: So maybe SKTexture would be better for that.

Comment: I'll try both of them, maybe some of them better for use in my game) Thanks again!